# What means the "element-update" in Shopware 6?

Tags: shopware6

I try to learn how i can create custom element for Shopware 6
although I cannot understand why we have to use the methods:

```
this.$emit('element-update', this.element);
```

in all SW Blocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All CMS element components should use the [`cms-element` mixin](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/36f7e07e03bdf4071d9d68e25b35f353081b50b3/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-cms/mixin/sw-cms-element.mixin.js#L11). The mixin has a model for the property `element` which is bound to the `element-update` event. By emitting this event with the value you update the property, as if you were using a child component with the form input binding `v-model`. Since [mutating props directly is considered an anti-pattern](https://michaelnthiessen.com/avoid-mutating-prop-directly/), this is a way to properly update it.